# Sometimes Jenkins can not checkout codes from svn

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I use Jenkins to make builds,sometimes the checkout codes process blocked ,wait and show no error log, you have to abort it and trigger a build again,then it might be OK.
is there anyone have this kind of issue?
I'm sure that the svn connection is OK and no one use svn that moment.

Comment: Perhaps someone is locking the working copy on the Jenkins server?

Comment: Also - Are you sure your commands are with non-interactive switches? It might be asking you to enter something and hanging there...